# C#: Bitmap Creation using bytes array

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am trying to dynamically create a Bitmap Image using byte array using following code

```
Bitmap GetImage()
{
    IntPtr  ip = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(imagesize);

    //some code to fill ip

    Image img =  new Bitmap(
                    w,
                    h,
                    -stride,
                    PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb,
                    (IntPtr)(ip.ToInt32() + imagesize - stride)
                    );

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem( ip); // Comment this line to work

    return img;
}

void SaveImage()
{
    Image img =  GetImage();
    img.save("test.bmp"); // This call fails
    img.Dispose();
}
```

Now my problem is I want to return a Bitmap but at the same time I don't want to keep the ip pointer as that memory allocated leaks. It is never freed.
How can I return a Image created with bytes array and without bothering the caller of the function GetImage() to free up the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way may be to create the bitmap (although in [similar code](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/blogfiles/Mandelbrot.cs) I've used a normal `byte[]` and then a `fixed` block, rather than directly using `AllocCoTaskMem`), and then create a *second* `Bitmap` of the same size. Call `Graphics.FromImage` on the second bitmap, then `Graphics.DrawImage` using the *first* bitmap to effectively copy the contents of the first bitmap onto the second. You can then call `Dispose` on the first bitmap, release the memory, and use the second bitmap which is basically a copy.

There may well be a more efficient way to do it if you're more proficient with image stuff, but if you're just looking for a way to get it to work, it's a starting point :)

EDIT: zachrrs's comment does indeed make things easier using the [Bitmap(Image)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx) constructor:

```
using (Bitmap original = new Bitmap(...))
{
    Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(originalImage);
    // Then return "copy" from your method, and you can free the
    // memory
}
```

Comment: I am getting the data from a unmanaged buffer which is nothing but DirectX SampleGrabber Filter thats the reason I am using AllocCoTaskMem

Comment: Fair enough :) Hope this works out for you. Let me know if you need a more complete sample.

Comment: You don't need to create an intermediary Graphics object, just create a new Bitmap instance with the original Bitmap instance in the constructor.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. I tried .Clone() but it didnt help can u explain why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions in advance, why not creating the bitmap and use the [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/039882h3.aspx) method to get the input buffer address?